# Check for life-cycle/phase and file existence in Maven and report error

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, build-process

I want to check in Maven if authentication data from property file is provided by developer during application testing if call **integration-test** life-cycle.

As state common practice it is bad to commit authentication data to source tree. Standard maven approach described at [settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).

But I don't like this approach (I want per checkout settings, not per dev-host!!) and want to provide **src/text/resources/auth.properties.example** in VCS (SVN/GIT/HG) as example and want to make code that check in Maven for existence of **src/text/resources/auth.properties** which is own per developer (or ever per project checkout!!) but only if **integration-test** phase was called (or any other after **integration-test** phase). If  executed any previous phases (like **compile** or **test**) - this checks must be disabled.

Maven **validate** phase designed to check build consistency (refer to [introduction-to-the-lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)). But there are no any checks for phases!! So I use **pre-integration-test** phase.

I write working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>my-app</name>

  <profiles>

    <profile>
      <id>existent.properties</id>
      <activation>
        <file>
          <missing>auth.properties</missing>
        </file>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <target>
                    <echo>In order to run integration-text life-cycle:</echo>
                    <echo>  1) Rename 'auth.properties.example' into 'auth.properties'.</echo>
                    <echo>  2) Fill 'auth.properties' with your own authentification data.</echo>
                    <fail message="Can't find 'auth.properties'."/>
                  </target>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

  <build>

    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <executions>

          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo>JUnit tests!</echo>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <target>
                <echo>Selenium tests!</echo>
              </target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

But as GNU Make guru I dislike above code. Am I right? Is it wrong use of Maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine (if a little over-engineered IMHO - I'd just put that kind of thing in a README / project wiki; the build ought to fail without the file when an attempt is made to read it)

You might also want to use the Enforcer goal instead of antrun: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html

Comment: Thanks for link to **maven-enforcer-plugin**!